# How to write the values of random arrays to the console app in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code but it writes the array number instead of its value.

```
int[] vektor = new int[7];
vektor[0] = 5;
vektor[1] = 12;
vektor[2] = 8;
vektor[3] = 18;
vektor[4] = 6;
vektor[5] = 9;
vektor[6] = 22;

Random v = new Random();
int tal = v.Next(vektor.Length);
System.Console.WriteLine(tal);
```

Comment: Well yes - you're not accessing the array element, you're just printing the index. You want `vektor[tal]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just outputting the number, not the item from teh array

```
System.Console.WriteLine(vektor[tal]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's hard to notice these details sometimes.